# serverless.yml how to use more than one path parameter?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'd like to configure a url of this pattern: `team/{tid}/player/{pid}`

I was trying to achieve this like that:

```
  get_player_info:
    handler: handlers.get_player_info
    timeout: 30
    warmup: true
    events:
      - http:
          path: team/{tid}/player/{pid}
          request:
            parameters:
              paths:
                tid: true
                pid: true
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer: ${self:provider.custom.authorizer}
```

But im getting an error when trying to deploy:

`ApiGatewayResourceAnalysisAidVar - A sibling ({uid}) of this resource already has a variable path part -- only one is allowed`

When using one path param everything works.

When removing the `request` part (which should validate it) I still get the same error.

Comment: What is `uid`? Is it defined in serverless.yml?

Comment: yes but on a different routes